# Inheritance constructor calling result

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

There are two classes. One inherited from the other one. Test results surprise me 
since I called the child class constructor and its method. However I do not call the super class constructor like this `new Cougar().go();`. But output shows the the super class constructor is called. Could you explain me why this happens?

```
public class Feline {
public String type = "f";

public Feline() {
    System.out.println("feline");
}
}

 public class Cougar extends Feline {

public Cougar() {
    System.out.println("cougar");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Cougar().go();
}

private void go() {
    type = "c";
    System.out.println(this.type + " " + super.type);
}

}
```

Output: feline
cougar
c c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass.

The constructor of the superclass is always invoked. You can call the desired constructor of your superclass using "super()" in the first line of your child class constructor.

For example:

```
public class Feline {
    public Feline() {
        System.out.println("Feline");
    }
    public Feline(String type) {
        System.out.println(type);
    }
    ... 
}

public class Cougar extends Feline{
    public Cougar() {
        super("Cougar");
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can't avoid the call to the superclass constructor. Check the edited answer for a possible solution

Comment: At your solution, cougar does not extend felina

Comment: That was a mistake, cougar extends feline as usual

Answer (score 0):

It is Because of line

```
new Cougar().go();
```

Inside the "go" method you have redefined the variable "type".
I hope it is making sense.

Comment: I tried new Cougar(); instead of new Cougar().go(); but result feline
cougar 
. It means that super constructor also called.

Answer (score 0):

When we invoke child class constructor,the java compiler automatically calls super class
constructor.If it is not present in super class,we will get compile time error.
If Object is the super class of our class then no issue since Object contains no-arg constructor.

**Reason-** The reason to have super constructor called is that if super class could have private fields which need to be initialized by its constructor.

[Refer this link for more info.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Comment: In my question's super class does not have private field

Comment: The reason indicates you could have private fields.

Answer (score 0):

When you call parameter-less constructor of the derived class the run-time automatically calls the parameter-less base class constructor before executing the derived class constructor. Because of this behavior you see feline cougar as first two string in your output.

Now for the 'c c' part of the output, you are not defining new String type variable in your Cougar class. You are using the same 'type' variable if the super class in go() method/function and setting it to "c". This is the reason you are getting 'c c' in the output.

Make Cougar as below. The syntax is C#.

```
 public class Cougar : Feline 
 {
    public String type = "c";

    public Cougar() 
    {
        Console.Write("cougar ");
    }

    static void Main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Cougar().go();
    }

    private void go() 
    {
        Console.Write(this.type + " " + base.type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but my question is why base class constructor calling despite not calling in subclass

Comment: It is a Java run-time behavior to call base class constructor upon calling derived constructor. All is parameter-less constructor.